# Customer next visit behavior forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting, random-forest, lstm, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I'm currently working with retail data about a store and the goal is to predict when each customer will visit the store again e.g customer id = 1 will probably visit again in 6 days(recency)

My dataset consists of N costumers each one with a different number of samples i.e each customer consist of a completely different time series

I've tried clustering customers and using random forests but the results were pretty bad because of the clustering

I'm trying LSTM's now, I'm feeding the entire the dataset after some feature engineering and still some poor results but better than the forest ones

Can someone recommend a different approach to modeling this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try survival analysis, where the events are store visits. This also allows you to use the most recent observations of 'not yet visited' as simply being right censored.